# How to reuse SASS variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scss-mixins, react-16

I have list of color variables in **`JavaScript`** file as an Object.

```
export const colors = [
{
    colorVariable: "$ui-background"
},
{
    colorVariable: "$ui-01"
},
{
    colorVariable: "$ui-02"
},
...
]
```

I created above object file based on **`scss`** file which have list of 50 colors. I used same name as scss variable So, i can use scss variable in my React component.

```
$carbon--theme: (
    ui-background: #ffffff,
    ui-01: #f3f3f3,
    ui-02: #ffffff,
    ...
)
```

I imported those colors to **`jsx`** file from color.js file.

```
import { colors } from './theme';
```

And i want use that color variable to give background of following div. I tried following way So, i can apply scss variable. But, not working.

```
component.jsx
```

Code:

```
Object.keys(colors).map(key => {
        return (
        <div style={{ background: colors[key].colorVariable }} className={'theme-color')} />
        )
})
```

I tried many things but nothing worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (It would be nice if i can use that variable in css (component.scss) file inside `theme-color` class. If not then ok ).

I am using react 16. Any help would be greatly appreciated and let me know if any questions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - the SASS variables does not exist on runtime. Are available only during compilation time.
The output CSS file does not include the SASS variables at all because and replaces any variable occurence with the raw value.

You might create CSS variables basing on the SCSS counterparts, then reuse the CSS variables in your code.

```
:root { /* or your element selector instead of `:root` so the variables will be scoped */
  --ui-background: #{map-get($carbon--theme, "ui-background")};
  --ui-01: #{map-get($carbon--theme, "ui-01")};
  --ui-02: #{map-get($carbon--theme, "ui-02")};
}
```

Just create additional SASS/SCSS file with the snippet above.

Then simply adjust the values in the `colors` variable.

```
export const colors = [
  {
    colorVariable: "var(--ui-background)"
  },
  {
    colorVariable: "var(--ui-01)"
  },
  {
    colorVariable: "var(--ui-02)"
  }
]
```

It perfectly works in runtime.

Bonus - if for some reason you need to reuse every color you might just iterate over the theme map using SASS's `@each` flow-control rule like:

```
:root { /* or your element selector */
  @each $name, $color in $carbon--theme {
    --#{$name}: #{$color};
  }
}
```

---

BTW
The `colors` variable is an array so you don't need to get the keys in order to iterate over it.

There is an additional problem that probably throws an error:
`className={'theme-color')}` - you have a closing paren `)` there.
Anyway, for the string values you can simply omit the JSX placeholders and pass the value directly in quotes.
Look at the fixed example:

```
colors.map(
  (item) => <div key={item.colorVariable} style={{ background: item.colorVariable }} className="theme-color"/>
);
```

If the `colors` array consists *only* with the color values you might simply replace it with array of strings like:
`['--ui01', '--ui02', ...]`

Then it is even simpler:

```
colors.map(
  (color) => <div key={color} style={{ background: color }} className="theme-color"/>
);
```

---

BTW #2.
If for some reason you don't want to use the CSS variables the other option is to use some library like [scss-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-to-json) that extracts the SCSS variables and outputs as JSON. This require an additional build step as well as importing/merging the JSON in your code base.

Comment: I edited my question. Is there any way that i can use this variable without changing in scss. `$carbon--theme: (
    ui-background: #ffffff,
    ui-01: #f3f3f3,
    ui-02: #ffffff,
    ...
)` Because it is used in different files by, other developer

Comment: Okay, understood, the thing is you need create your own `scss` file, not modify the existing one :)